# How to create a modal window in pyqt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, modal-dialog, pyqt, pyqt4

I looked into the documentation and i found   'self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)'.
I added this function to my '**init**' function, but however still was not able to create a modal dialog box.

Any help will be appreciated,
Thank You.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Using a QDialog in combination with its `exec` method, should be sufficient and avoids the need to set the modality explicitly: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`QDialog` has `setModal()` as found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#modal-prop).

As the docs state:

> By default, this property is `False` and `show()` pops up the dialog as
>   modeless. Setting this property to true is equivalent to setting
>   `QWidget.windowModality` to `Qt.ApplicationModal`.

As @sebastian noted you could use `exec()`. However it is better to use `exec_()` as the one sebastian mentioned is also a python call.

Example:

```
my_dialog = QDialog(self) 
my_dialog.exec_()  # blocks all other windows until this window is closed.
```

If this doesn't help please post your code and I will have a look.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time. I realised that what i was looking for was a system modal dialog, i should have read the docs properly. I'll edit the question. I apologise, but do you know if it is possible to create a system modal dialog in ppyqt for linux. Thanks.

Comment: By System Modal you mean that your window should be on top of every other applications window? This is generally a bad idea and will end up frustrating your end user(s).

Comment: Its actually a license agreement for a linux distro.

Comment: FWIW: I of course meant to use `exec_`, I just happen to use the Qt reference usually. Since `exec` not only a python call but a keyword - the `exec` method can't exist in python anyway.

Comment: how to show a dialog blocks only some windows rather than the entire application?